# Should I delete my question?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete

I have [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44191957/reloading-scene-causes-scripts-to-stop-working) on Stack Overflow.

When I originally posted the question, I only posted the bare minimum code to help answerers diagnose the problem quickly. Now, I have realized that piece of code is not what was the problem.

My question is should I delete my question? I am thinking to do so because it will not help (or even hinder) future users who also have this problem. On the other hand, it gives me a message warning me not to do it.

What should I do in this situation?

Comment: Be careful of the [meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect)

Comment: Hey Yummy - it's totally commonplace, especially in tags with a lot of learner programmers such as Unity - that you post a problem concerning X, and you find out ultimately that your particular problem was completely unrelated (whether just a simple typo, accidentally using *timescale* in your case - or whatever).  **This is totally normal on SO**, you **do not have to delete** your question.  Even as is, your QA page has some useful information that will help others!  Enjoy and go on to your next QA !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is:

## yes, it's totally normal and commonplace...

on SO that the programming problem at hand turns out to be "totally unrelated".  (So, you made a simple syntax error, or whatever.)

This is completely normal on SO, and there's **no need to delete the question**.  The QA still as a rule has value, after all - it answers a useful question!